# Data extension Inner Join - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

I am trying to join 2 data extensions and input the result to a third data extension:

```
SELECT [Account ID] AS [Account ID], [Created Date Backend] AS [Created Date] 
FROM [DE A]  A
INNER JOIN [DE B] B
WHERE A.[Account ID] = B.[Lead ID]
```

Currently getting a syntax error:

> The query syntax is invalid
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

When conducting a JOIN function, you need to specify what the 2 tables are joining on.

**Try this:**

```
SELECT 
[Account ID] AS 'Account ID'
,[Created Date Backend] AS 'Created Date'
FROM [DE A] A
INNER JOIN [DE B] B ON A.[Account ID] = B.[Lead ID]
```

Note that you may need to specify what table *Account ID* and *Created Date Backend* come from.

**Reference**: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

This image will help you understand the basics of JOINs:
[image: SQL Joins]

Comment: DE B has a column called amounts. I am trying to aggregate the value in the amounts column for those A.[Account ID] = B.[Lead ID]. I am trying the following query SELECT A.[Account ID] AS [Account ID], A.[Created Date Backend] AS [Created Date], sum(B.[Amount]) AS [Amount]  FROM [DE A]  AS A INNER JOIN [DE B] AS B 
ON A.[Account ID] = B.[Lead ID]
GROUP BY B.[Lead ID]. However got the following error : Column 'C7229974.A.Account ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.